# I cant move my div, up? yet i can move it left and right?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a simple website, and I have made a div's with a frosted glass effect, now I can position it left and right yet I can't seem to move it up!? the div in question has the name of product panel.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }

.background{
    background-image: url("http://www.kubipet.com/data/out/55/iwp779807523-electrical-wallpapers.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}


#header-frosted{
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
   
}



    
.jumbotron-fluid{
   background: inherit; 
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right:0px;
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   width: 100%;  
   color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
   
}


.display-3{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:50px;
    
}


.navbar.main {
  
   background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 0%;
    
    
}
.nav-pills{
 margin-top:2px;
text-align: center;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#tab{
    color: white;    
}

#tab:hover {
    background-color: rgb(63, 60, 60);
}



.frosted-glass {
    
    width:10%;
    height:auto;
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px,30px,30px,30px;
    padding: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }
  
  .frosted-glass::before {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    filter: blur(5px);

  }
  #product-panel{
    width:500px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align:left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
  
   
   
    

}
#contact-details{
    width:200px;
    height: 330px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
    
  }

  #details{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
   enter code here

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="fonts\css\font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css\KAD-css.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body class="background">
  
  
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid frosted-glass" id="header-frosted" >
                <div class="container img-responsive">
                  
                  <h1 class="display-3">Random Title</h1>
                  
                </div>
              </div>

              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  navbar-default main" >
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"id="tab">Random Title</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-centre" id="myNavbar">
                      <ul class="nav  nav-pills center-pills">
                          <li class="nav-item ">

  
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="tab"> Random1
                               
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ">

  
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random2
                                 
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item">

  
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random3
    
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </nav>'

<div class="frosted-glass" id="contact-details">
   <h3 id="details">Contact Details</h3>
 <p><strong>Name:</strong>John Doe</p>
 <p><strong>Phone Number:</strong> 000000000</p>
 <h3>Address:</h3>
 <strong><p>Random Title.</p>
 <p>PO Box 000</p>
 <p>Random Town, Random Country</p>
 <p>000</p>
 </strong>
</div>
 <!--Product Panel-->
<div class="frosted-glass" id="product-panel">
This is the div in question.


  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Bearing in mind i just started out with web design some help and input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://codepen.io/Zaraa/pen/zRPpoM?editors=1100)
is the codepen, tell me if it solved your problem

put your
`<div class="frosted-glass" id="product-panel">`

before`<div class="frosted-glass" id="contact-details">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="fonts\css\font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css\KAD-css.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Website</title>      
            <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
            <!-- language: lang-css -->
        <style>
                *{
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                   }

                .background{
                    background-image: url("http://www.kubipet.com/data/out/55/iwp779807523-electrical-wallpapers.jpg");
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-attachment: fixed;
                    background-size: cover;
                }
                #header-frosted{
                    background: inherit;
                    position: relative;
                    width:100%;
                    height: 200px;                 
                }                   
                .jumbotron-fluid{
                   background: inherit; 
                   padding-left: 0px;
                   padding-right:0px;
                   padding-top:0px;
                   padding-bottom: 0px;
                   margin-bottom: 0px;
                   width: 100%;  
                   color:rgb(0, 0, 0);                 
                }
                .display-3{
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-top:50px;                
                }
                .navbar.main {                
                   background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
                    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                    margin-top: 0px;
                    border-style: none;
                    border-radius: 0%;
                }
                .nav-pills{
                 margin-top:2px;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top:5px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                }

                #tab{
                    color: white;    
                }

                #tab:hover {
                    background-color: rgb(63, 60, 60);
                }
                .frosted-glass {

                    width:10%;
                    height:auto;
                    background: inherit;
                    position: relative;
                    z-index: 1;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    margin: 30px,30px,30px,30px;
                    padding: 2rem;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                  }               
                  .frosted-glass::before {
                    width:auto;
                    height:auto;
                    content: "";
                    position: absolute;
                    z-index: -1;
                    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
                    background: inherit;
                    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
                    filter: blur(5px);

                  }
                  #product-panel{
                    width:500px;
                    height: 400px;
                    text-align:left;
                    position: absolute;
                    margin-top:20px;
                }
                #contact-details{
                    width:200px;
                    height: 330px;
                    text-align:left;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-bottom: 100px;
                    position: relative;

                  }

                  #details{
                    text-align: center;
                }
                /*
                Start of Code - Laxmikant Killekar
                */
                body{
                    overflow-x: hidden;
                }
                /*
                End of Code - Laxmikant Killekar
                */

        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="background">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid frosted-glass" id="header-frosted" >
            <div class="container img-responsive">            
              <h1 class="display-3">Random Title</h1>             
            </div>
          </div>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  navbar-default main" >
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"id="tab">Random Title</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-centre" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav  nav-pills center-pills">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="tab"> Random1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random2 </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                        
                     </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>

            <!-- Start of Code - Laxmikant Killekar -->             

            <div class="fluid-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!--Product Panel-->
                        <div class="frosted-glass" id="product-panel">
                        This is the div in question.                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                        <div class="frosted-glass" id="contact-details">
                             <h3 id="details">Contact Details</h3>
                             <p><strong>Name:</strong>John Doe</p>
                             <p><strong>Phone Number:</strong> 000000000</p>
                             <h3>Address:</h3>
                             <strong><p>Random Title.</p>
                             <p>PO Box 000</p>
                             <p>Random Town, Random Country</p>
                             <p>000</p>
                             </strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End of Code - Laxmikant Killekar-->

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Most important part for any web page is its wire frame structure. So your html structure should be optimal. I have just structure the html code and used bootstrap classes to set page as per your requirement. Please check and let me know if this solve your issue. (new to stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Add top:(value)px to this

```
 #product-panel{
    width:500px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align:left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
    top:320px;
}
```

and you can change position to it

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }

.background{
    background-image: url("http://www.kubipet.com/data/out/55/iwp779807523-electrical-wallpapers.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}


#header-frosted{
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
   
}



    
.jumbotron-fluid{
   background: inherit; 
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right:0px;
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   width: 100%;  
   color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
   
}


.display-3{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:50px;
    
}


.navbar.main {
  
   background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 0%;
    
    
}
.nav-pills{
 margin-top:2px;
text-align: center;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#tab{
    color: white;    
}

#tab:hover {
    background-color: rgb(63, 60, 60);
}



.frosted-glass {
    
    width:10%;
    height:auto;
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px,30px,30px,30px;
    padding: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }
  
  .frosted-glass::before {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    filter: blur(5px);

  }
  #product-panel{
    width:500px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align:left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:20px;
    top:320px;
   
   
    

}
#contact-details{
    width:200px;
    height: 330px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
    
  }

  #details{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
enter code here

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="fonts\css\font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css\KAD-css.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body class="background">
  
  
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid frosted-glass" id="header-frosted" >
                <div class="container img-responsive">
                  
                  <h1 class="display-3">Random Title</h1>
                  
                </div>
              </div>

              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  navbar-default main" >
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"id="tab">Random Title</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-centre" id="myNavbar">
                      <ul class="nav  nav-pills center-pills">
                          <li class="nav-item ">

  
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="tab"> Random1
                               
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ">

  
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random2
                                 
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item">

  
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random3
    
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </nav>'

<div class="frosted-glass" id="contact-details">
   <h3 id="details">Contact Details</h3>
 <p><strong>Name:</strong>John Doe</p>
 <p><strong>Phone Number:</strong> 000000000</p>
 <h3>Address:</h3>
 <strong><p>Random Title.</p>
 <p>PO Box 000</p>
 <p>Random Town, Random Country</p>
 <p>000</p>
 </strong>
</div>
 <!--Product Panel-->
<div class="frosted-glass" id="product-panel">
This is the div in question.


  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use more than one items in a line, it should satisfy the width proportion
So,  give width percentage '%' instead of pixel 'px',
here you can use float:left to include more than one item in a line.
Try to use width in percentage, it is the way most developers use

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }

.background{
    background-image: url("http://www.kubipet.com/data/out/55/iwp779807523-electrical-wallpapers.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}


#header-frosted{
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
   
}



    
.jumbotron-fluid{
   background: inherit; 
   padding-left: 0px;
   padding-right:0px;
   padding-top:0px;
   padding-bottom: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   width: 100%;  
   color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
   
}


.display-3{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:50px;
    
}


.navbar.main {
  
   background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 0%;
    
    
}
.nav-pills{
 margin-top:2px;
text-align: center;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#tab{
    color: white;    
}

#tab:hover {
    background-color: rgb(63, 60, 60);
}



.frosted-glass {
    
    width:10%;
    height:auto;
    background: inherit;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px,30px,30px,30px;
    padding: 2rem;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
  }
  
  .frosted-glass::before {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3000px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    filter: blur(5px);

  }
  #product-panel{
    width:70%;
    height: 400px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;   
}

#contact-details{
    width:30%;
    height: 330px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    float:left;
    
  }

  #details{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
enter code here

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="fonts\css\font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css\KAD-css.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>Website</title>
</head>

<body class="background">
  
  
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid frosted-glass" id="header-frosted" >
                <div class="container img-responsive">
                  
                  <h1 class="display-3">Random Title</h1>
                  
                </div>
              </div>

              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  navbar-default main" >
                  <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                      </button>
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"id="tab">Random Title</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-centre" id="myNavbar">
                      <ul class="nav  nav-pills center-pills">
                          <li class="nav-item ">

  
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="tab"> Random1
                               
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ">

  
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random2
                                 
                                </a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item">

  
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#"id="tab"> Random3
    
                                  </a>
                                </li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </nav>'


 <!--Product Panel-->
<div class="frosted-glass" id="product-panel">
This is the div in question.


  
</div>

<div class="frosted-glass" id="contact-details">
   <h3 id="details">Contact Details</h3>
 <p><strong>Name:</strong>John Doe</p>
 <p><strong>Phone Number:</strong> 000000000</p>
 <h3>Address:</h3>
 <strong><p>Random Title.</p>
 <p>PO Box 000</p>
 <p>Random Town, Random Country</p>
 <p>000</p>
 </strong>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```